# Column in horizontal middle of page

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I want to write a table with 3 columns.
The second should be in the middle (horizontally) of the page.

Thanks, Adrian.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you be a bit more precise about your needs?

Comment: Sure. Basically the middle column will consist of arrows, pointing from left to right or right to left. The outer columns will contain text or math objects. I think it would be a better style if the arrows would be horizontally aligned to the center of the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this (all horizontal and vertical rules only for explanation and can be removed):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,tabularx}
\begin{document}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{N}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|R{5cm}|N|m{5cm}|} \hline
Lorem ipsum dolor sit & $\longrightarrow$ & Lorem ipsum dolor sit \\ \hline
Lorem ipsum dolor sit & $\longrightarrow$ & Lorem ipsum dolor sit \\ \hline
Lorem ipsum dolor sit & $\longrightarrow$ & Lorem ipsum dolor sit \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

The `tabularx` is used for the table to occupy total line width. The two outer columns are specified by a certain width so that the second column can be centered w.r.t. the line width and will have its width equal to the remaining length (so, the X-column type is required).

Moreover, to center the second column w.r.t. cell contents, we use a `\newcolumntype` defined as:

```
\newcolumntype{N}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
```

which requires the `array` package. Also the first column is right-justified by the definition:

```
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
```

The third column is already left-justified.

**Edit:**

With a `\newenvironment` defined as:

```
\newenvironment{ABC}{\tabularx{\linewidth}{R{5cm}Nm{5cm}}}
{\endtabularx}

\begin{ABC}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit & $\longrightarrow$ & Lorem ipsum dolor sit \\ 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit & $\longrightarrow$ & Lorem ipsum dolor sit \\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit & $\longrightarrow$ & Lorem ipsum dolor sit \\ 
\end{ABC}
```

You will have the same results.

[image]

Comment: I just tried to define a new environment for convenience:
`\newenvironment{ABC}{\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{R{5cm}Nm{5cm}}}{\end{tabularx}}` but TeX does complain... Do you see why?

Comment: @user52963 Please see my edit.

Comment: Ok. That works fine. Thank you again! Why doesn't the `\begin` approach?